# GO: error serving templates with html/template

Tags: go

I'm using html/template to serve html but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly. I've only pasted the relevant code below (not complete):

This is my Go code:

```
func homehandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    userName := getUserName(r) //this is defined somewhere
    if userName != "" {
        t := template.Must(template.New("Tele").Parse(homePage))
    t.Execute(w, ReadData()) //ReadData() is a function that reads from the MySQL database and returns a string array
    } else {
        (...some code)
    }
}

func ReadData() ([]string) {
    db, _ := sql.Open("mysql", "user1@/my_db")
    (...some code)    

    rows, err := db.Query("select tweet from posts where username = ?", AddUser.Name) //AddUser is defined somewhere
    (...some code)

    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(&tweet)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    v := append(tweetarray, tweet)
    fmt.Println(v)
    return v
    }
    return []string{}
}
```

The html portion in the Go code:

```
const homePage = `
<html>
<h1>hi {{ .userName}}</h1>
<form action="/home/tweets" method="POST">
<label for="name">Tweet</label>
<input type="text" id="tweet" name="twt"</input>
<button type="Tweet">Tweet</button>
<h2>{{range $i := .tweetarray}} {{ $i }} {{end}}</h2>
`
```

The HTML doesn't appear at all. What am I doing wrong in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Check your errors!** (sorry for the bold, but this is the answer to so many Go questions)

`t.Execute()` returns an error because you have malformed html in your template.

```
html/template:Tele: "<" in attribute name: "</input>\n<button type=\"Tweet\">Tw"
```

When troubleshooting something like this, try running each of the parts in isolation, or at least log some debugging information to go with it.

Comment: Thanks. I've been checking, and I think the problem is my ReadData() function. It's only returning me data from the first row it finds and does not return the other data from other rows with the same identifier. But I don't know why ReadData() is doing that.

Comment: no, your error is exactly where I said: `html/template:Tele: "<" in attribute name: "</input>\n<button type=\"Tweet\">Tw"`